# Error Exception Array to string conversion

Tags: api, laravel-5.8

I want to have a response in postman for my API... but when I send  a raw in body of postman
I faced to array to string conversion error

> Error Exception (E_NOTICE)
> Array to string conversion

this is my raw

```
{
    "account_type": "real",
    "address": "12131",
    "card_bank": "",
    "city": {
        "id": 436,
        "name": "مشهد",
        "state_id": 11,
        "state_name": "خراسان رضوی"
    },
    "code_melli": "",
    "email": "",
    "family": "اسداله پور",
    "id": 171,
    "mobile": "0911111111",
    "name": "مهدی",
    "phone": "",
    "role": "usual",
    "card": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": 2,
            "id_product": 267,
            "productM": null,
            "seller": null,
            "id_seller": 0,
            "totalPrice": "97500"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": 3,
            "id_product": 696,
            "productM": null,
            "seller": null,
            "id_seller": 0,
            "totalPrice": "115000"
        }
    ],
    "state": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "خراسان رضوی"
    }
   
}
```

and this is my web service
about this route

```
public function ChangeInformation(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'name' => 'required',
                'family' => 'required',
                'mobile' => 'required',

            ],
            [
                'name.required' => 'لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید',
                'family.required' => 'لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید',
                'mobile.required' => 'لطفا موبایل خود را وارد کنید',
            ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            self::$result_json['error'] = 1;
            self::$result_json['error_code'] = 1;
            self::$result_json['msg'] = $validator->messages()->first();

        }
        else{
            $user =  DB::table('user_app')
             ->where('id', $request->get('token'))
             ->first();

            $input = $request->except('img');

            /*if ($request->hasFile('img')) {


                $file_param = $request->file('img');

                $fileName = $file_param->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = substr($fileName, 0, strrpos($fileName, '.'));
                $fileName = str_replace(' ', '', $fileName);
                $Random_Number = rand(0, 9999);
                $name_file_new = $fileName . '-' . $Random_Number . '.' . $file_param->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //$thumb_img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/avatars/';
                $file_param->move($destinationPath, $name_file_new);
                $path_file = 'uploads/avatars/' . $name_file_new;
                $input['img'] = $path_file;

            }
            else {

                self::$result_json['error'] = 1;
                self::$result_json['error_code'] = 1;
                self::$result_json['msg'] = 'تصویر نادرست است .';

            }*/
             DB::table('user_app')
                ->where('id',$user->id)
                ->update($input);


            $city = DB::table('cities')
                ->where('id', $input['shahr'])
                ->first();

            $state = DB::table('state')
                ->where('id', $input['ostan'])
                ->first();


            $user_data = DB::table('user_app')
                ->where('id',$user->id)
                ->select('account_type', 'address','email','card_bank', 'shahr as city',
                    'family', 'id', 'mobile', 'name', 'img', 'phone', 'role', 'ostan as state', 'zip_code')
                ->first();


            $user_data->city = $city;
            $user_data->state = $state;

            self::$result_json['success'] = 1;
            self::$result_json['user_data'] = $user_data;

        }
```

it worked when I send data in form_data but do not work in raw when i send my data

Comment: Have you tried sending data by changing type Text to JSON in postman?

Comment: Yes,I had @Shervin Ivari

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your associative array into json object format using "json_encode() function" which is string, postman cannot read array, I hope this one will do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).